# system crash with Ubuntu 17.10 32 Bit kernel 4.13 on startx

Tags: kernel, xorg, 17.10

After the last release-upgrade on my notebook, I got trouble. But in the end I figured out, that the complete system crash was caused by the kernel 4.13.,
together with the start of the GUI. (startx)
Going step by step, I realized that with the kernel 4.10, I was able to startx. So it seams to be a kind of kernel bug.

What can I do now to detect the real reason for this in more detail?

Comment: Start with these pages - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Backtracing

Comment: I ended up with  backuping my system, and reinstall a new Ubuntu 17.10 64 bit version. I don't know why but the 32 Bit 17.10, made several problems. Not only the X11. Now everything works!